# Is this a reduced-relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> The **books available** for borrowing in this library do not interest us.

Is the sentence above a reduced relative clause?

Can "which were" be understood to be between **books** and **available**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The books [available for borrowing in this library] do not interest us.*

No, the bracketed element is not a reduced relative clause; in fact it's not a clause at all but an adjective phrase modifying "books".

It can be converted to a relative clause by the addition of "that are", as in:

*The books [that are available for borrowing in this library] do not interest us.*

The ill-named 'reduced' relative clauses are non-finites, as in:

*Students [living on campus] must respect the midnight curfew.*

Comment: Thank you .For your example sentence, is "Students living on campus..." the equivalent of " Students who live on campus..." ?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I would avoid the term 'reduced relative clause' for the former, since there is no possibility of it containing a relative phrase. We cant say "Students who living on campus".